# Class not found exception hadoop

Tags: java, class, maven, hadoop, mapreduce

Hi i am running map reduce word count in hadoop.I am getting this error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: -files
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:270)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:205)
```

But when i export as runnable jar it is working.But when i trying through maven.it is not working.Please help to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

When you export you jar as runnable jar the main class of your application is defined in the manifest. If you start it from maven you have to define your main class. The exception you show means that The *run* method expects a class as parameter whereas you defined "-files". So just add the full qualified name of your main class of your mapreduce job before "-files" and it should work.

Edit: See [documentation](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.4/commands_manual.html#jar) for an example. The command will look like the following line.

> hadoop jar myjar.jar com.mycompany.task.Main -files ...

Comment: How to define the class name in run method

Comment: Google is you friend. To make your life super easy I added the call and a link to the documentation in my answer. Just add the full qualified class name behind the jar file (or in Maven it might be the first argument).